# Passing textbox value from one file to another

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

as i am building my first React application in particular react-native application. I want to pass a textbox value from one js file to another. Can somebody help me how it should be done?

my code in first.js

```
                    <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'left', width: width - 60 }}>{GLOBAL.Email}</Text>
                    <View style={[styles.textInputFrame, { width: width - 48, }]} >
                        <TextInput
                            keyboardType='email-address'
                            style={styles.textInput}
                            onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                            returnKeyType='next'
                            onSubmitEditing={() => this.refs.passwordInput.focus()}
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        />
                    </View>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you be more clear on what do you mean by `one js file to another`? Did you mean to say `Components`?

Comment: If you want to pass info from one `component` to another `component`, you can pass it in as a `prop`. If the value will not be used only on one other `component`/file I would suggest you look into using `Context` or `Redux`

Answer (score 0):

1. Store textbox value as a global state by using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), or any libraries like Redux, Mobx, ...
2. Pass textbox value ( email state of first component ) as a property of your second component

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @khanh solution you can also

3. Create your own data store which you will import in your different files to store your data. I highly recommend using the observer pattern for this one (see https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/observer-design-pattern).
4. Send a event on which you can subscribe anywhere in your app, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-event-listeners for this one.